# if() else() statement problem ... :/

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Can someone please help me with the "if else statement", I'm having problem with this script:

```
    $('div#wrapper div.teamwrapper:odd').addClass('odd');

    $('div.teamwrapper').each(function(index){
      if($('div.teamwrapper').hasClass('odd')){
        $(this).css('top', index*35);
      }else{
        $(this).css('top', index*28);
      }
    });
```

My problem is that,the script above only execute the parameters inside the "if statement". It applies the parameter inside the "if statement" to all "div.teamwrapper" even if the object don't have an "odd" class. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried an alert() , each 'if' and in 'else'!!

Comment: `console.log` would be better, alert should not really be used anymore.

Answer (score 3):

```
  $('div#wrapper div.teamwrapper:odd').addClass('odd');

    $('div.teamwrapper').each(function(index){
      if($(this).hasClass('odd')){
        $(this).css('top', index*35);
      }else{
        $(this).css('top', index*28);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
$('div#wrapper div.teamwrapper:odd').addClass('odd');

    $('div.teamwrapper').each(function(index){
      if($(this).hasClass('odd')){
        $(this).css('top', index*35);
      }else{
        $(this).css('top', index*28);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Access object by `this` inside function

```
$('div.teamwrapper').each(function(index){
    if($(this).hasClass('odd')){
    $(this).css('top', index*35);
    }else{
    $(this).css('top', index*28);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you may try this

replace `$('div.teamwrapper').hasClass('odd')` with `$(this).hasClass('odd')`

this seems more logical than what you have written.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, the easiest would be to use the css method with a function that will set the value. You can read about it [in the jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2).

```
$('div#wrapper div.teamwrapper:odd').addClass('odd');

$('div.teamwrapper').css('top', function(index, value){
  if ($(this).hasClass('odd')) {
    return index*35;
  } else {
    return index*28;
  }
});
```

If you really want to use the each method, do it like this:

```
$('div.teamwrapper').each(function(index){
  var $me=$(this);
  if($me.hasClass('odd')){
    $me.css('top', index*35);
  }else{
    $me.css('top', index*28);
  }
});
```

You should save the value of `$(this)` first into a variable (like `$me`), and then use that variable afterwards, this will save you a bit of resources, and a good programming practice anyways.